# PHP code for forcefully Disable Classic editor and show up only Block editor for specific custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, editor, wordpress-gutenberg, developer-tools

I am looking for PHP code that can be added to functions.php to forcefully Disable Classic editor for a CPT and show up only Block editor in a specific CPT, maintaining all other contents in classic editor.

PHP code that can be added to functions.php
Not looking for plugins

Comment: Checkout my answer. Hope that solves your query.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here. Add this in your functions.php and replace the `movie` with your CPT and the classic editor will be disabled.

```
function disable_classic_editor_for_custom_post_type( $use_block_editor, $post ) {
    // Enable Block Editor for the custom post type.
    if ( 'movie' === $post->post_type ) {
        return true;
    }
    return $use_block_editor;
}
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', 'disable_classic_editor_for_custom_post_type', 10, 2 );
```